# Building a filtering interface using Mongo

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm playing with Mongo now. One of the first things I do when I'm playing with new web tech is build a simple ecommerce site as I find that it gives a very good overview as to how to do a lot of things.

I have the items for sale in the database, each item has fields such as manufacturer, product type (ie usb storage, hard drive, memory, ssd), capacity (in gb), etc.

The site has the ability for a search to be done and will return all products. I want to build a filter in a sidebar that lists all manufacturers, capacities, product types, etc that the search returned, along with item counts. So for example, if hard drive is a filter applied then usb storage, memory & ssd is removed from the product type in the sidebar.

I would expect this would be like a DISTINCT on the searched documents along with the respective count.

TLDR: When I get a query result set from Mongo, what is the most efficient way to get a distinct list of various fields for filtering, along with the number of items in the result set that these field values apply to.

Comment: What you are describing here is called a "faceted search" which you might find that various specialized "text search" products do already and might be better suited to your purposes. For one approach on building a "facet list" with MongoDB see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27883584/5031275). Or in more depth [here](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/59757486344/faceted-search-with-mongodb)

Comment: @BlakesSeven  That's pretty much an answer; go ahead and post it as such.

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti Well I didn't post it as an "answer" because there are various exaples of people saying use something like Elasticsearch or Solr as well as a few variants on the approach as explained in the linked answer and blog post.

Comment: @BlakesSeven I think what you're saying is correct. I didn't realise this term was called Faceting. I'm going to use ElasticSearch I think after reading what you wrote, but I need to do more research. Go ahead and post, I'll mark it as the answer.