# PHP & MongoDB query - get list of common values across documents

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb

I'm currently working on an e-commerce solution of my own.

First, a product document look like that -

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("...."),
    "sku" : "",
    "manufacturer" : "", // Manufacturer
    "quantity" : 0,
    "price" : 0,
    "currency" : "", // Currency code
    "warranty" : "", // Yes/No/True/False
    "installation" : "", // Installiton type/required
    "images" : [], // array of img paths
    "creation" : ISODate("...."),
    "lastModified" : ISODate("...."),
    "details" : [], // array of object each for different language
    "properties" : [ 
        {
            "property" : "", // property name, unique
            "value" : "" // propery value
        }
    ],
    "customize" : [ 
        {
            "property" : "", // property name
            "type" : "", // input type: radio, select, etc.
            "options" : [ 
                {
                    "id" : 1, // numeric id
                    "option" : "", // option text
                    "cost" : 0.0 // option additional price
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "categories" : [], // array of objects {category:1, subs[2,3,4]}
    "excludes" : [],
    "shipping" : [], // array of objects {location:FR, price:5, additional: 1}
}
```

So, what I want to be able to do is to get a list of filters (max of 5, the most common).

Filters I need:

1. simple filters - all values available for manufacturer + count for each
2. nested filters - all values available for array_of_obj.x + count (example: properties.property)
3. even more nested for the customize array and categories array, but it will be just a bonus.

How can I achieve each one? Will it be too heavy?

In case the query will be too complex, will it be better to get all products to an array of products (I'm using setTypeMap in order to unserialize the data directly to my php class) and then play with array_column, foreach etc.?

Comment: You mean "facet counts" I presume. And things like the "distinct list of manufacturer" and the "count" for that distinct value. It's kind generally represented as "lots of queries" with small result sets. That's why their called "facets", and that's why there is a [`$facet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) aggregation pipeline stage. Your question could be clearer, but that's were you should start looking.

Comment: You might also take a look at [MongoDB queries optimisation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27883584/2313887) which is actually all about "facets", and done long before that "parallel pipelines operator" even existed. As such, there are some techniques mentioned there which can "optimize" the gathering of facet counts as well as aid in document selection by such "tags". As Trivia, my first MongoDB usage was also for e-commerce, and I can see you making the same mistakes as I originally did. You are definitely going to need to rethink "nesting arrays within arrays", which is a really bad idea.

Comment: Thanks for your help @NeilLunn can you offer different structure? or just show me how you managed to work around your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Neil Lunn, I managed to solve my problem by using `$facet` aggregation pipeline stage, even with the complex structure of an `array => object => array`.

I'll post my code with a full explanation soon, in order to help others here.